# compiled function does not extract elements from a matrix, proceed with uncompiled evaluation

Tags: matrix, compile, tensors

I have written a small piece of code for a function that extracts certain elements from a matrix and then sum them and return the result. Although the uncompiled version works, when I try to switch to a compilable function something goes wrong:

```
microstep = Compile [{{matrix, _Integer, 2}, {arraydim, _Integer}},
Module[{

tempmatrix = matrix,
randomtuple = {x , y } = RandomInteger[{1, arraydim}, 2], (*select a random element of  the matrix*)

down = {Mod[x + 1, arraydim, 1], y},  (*find the nearest neighbours  and *)
up = {Mod[x - 1, arraydim, 1], y},    (*impose periodic boundary conditions*)
left = {x, Mod[ y - 1, arraydim, 1]},
right = {x, Mod[y + 1, arraydim, 1]}, spindiff},

spindiff = Total[Extract[tempmatrix, #] & /@ {up, down, left, right}]

   ],
CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]

microstep[confiniziale, 5]
```

where confiniziale is a   5x5 matrix whose elements  are randomly chosen between -1 and 1.

```
confiniziale = RandomChoice[{-1, 1}, {lato, lato}];
```

The plan was to further develop  her  and implement a    Metropolis algorithm. 
The errors i get are :

> 1) Extract: "Position specification {4.,2.} in Extract[*mymatrix,,{4.,2.}] is not
>   applicable

and

> 2) CompiledFunction : " compiled expression Extract[*mymatrix,{4.,2.}]
>   should be a rank 2 tensor of machine-size real numbers

and then the function continues using the uncompiled version giving the right result. what am I missing? any tips?

Comment: Does ``spindiff  =  Total[Compile`GetElement[tempmatrix, ##] & @@@ {up, down, left, right}]`` work?

Comment: @kglr it says 
" Compilation of COmpile`GetElement(tempmatrix,##1) &)@@Compile`GetElement(SystemPrivateCompileSymbol(0),SystemPrivateCompileSymbol(1)) is not supported for the function argument CompileGetElement(tempmatrix,##1)&. The only function arguments supported are Times,Plus,or List. Evaluation will use the uncompiled function"

Comment: It's worth pointing out that `randomtuple = {x , y } = RandomInteger[{1, arraydim}, 2]` is also causing trouble here. `x` and `y` isn't localized.

Comment: @xzczd ah yes , thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would write your `CompiledFunction`:

```
microstep = Compile[{{matrix, _Integer, 2}},
  Module[{x, y, dimx, dimy},
   dimx = Compile`GetElement[Dimensions[matrix], 1];
   dimy = Compile`GetElement[Dimensions[matrix], 2];
   x = RandomInteger[{1, dimx}];
   y = RandomInteger[{1, dimy}];
   Plus[
    Compile`GetElement[matrix, Mod[x + 1, dimx, 1], y],
    Compile`GetElement[matrix, Mod[x - 1, dimx, 1], y],
    Compile`GetElement[matrix, x, Mod[y - 1, dimy, 1]],
    Compile`GetElement[matrix, x, Mod[y + 1, dimy, 1]]
    ]
   ],
  CompilationTarget -> "C",
  RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
  ]
```

The major issue was that `Extract` is not compilable and `Compile` seems to be unable to build a reasonable call to the main evaluator. Anyway, you wouldn't have fun with a compiled function that has to call the main evaluator (slow).

Another mild issue:

You use quite a lot of tensor operations like `left = {x, Mod[ y - 1, arraydim, 1]},` for vectors of length `2`. That's very inefficient within `Compile` since each of these calls will involve a `CopyTensor` which is notoriously slow. And in the end, you have to retrieve the elements of these vectors again, undoing the whole costly process of putting things into vectors.

Comment: thanks ! where can i find the documentation for `GetElement ? i couldn't find it on the wolfram center.

Comment: There is not documentation for it, but it gets frequently used on this site. In a nutshell, it is a read-only variant of `Part` with the difference  that does not check every time whether the indices are within the bounds of the array. That makes it considerably faster than `Part` but the programmer has to do the bound checks. Otherwise the kernel will quit when the function is called.

Comment: one last question : do you know if Mathematica   speed up by a noteworthy amount    if i switch to helical boundary conditions? or  the Mod function is pretty much irrelevant for the absolute time?

Comment: `Mod` is very quick. No need to take pain for optimizing it away.

Comment: sorry to bother you again henrik but  when i try to check whether the sum (spinsum= Plus[...])  is lesser than 0 i get a warning message that tells me that spinsum should be a machine-size real number. Do you know hw to solve this problem?

Comment: ops i forgot  to tag you @Henrik

Comment: You can change the argument pattern from `{{matrix, _Integer, 2}}` to `{{matrix, _Real, 2}}`. Then `matrix` gets automatically converted.

Comment: isn't it possible to transform 0 from a real to an approximated integer  instead of transforming the matrix?i tried switching 0 with 0. but it didn't work

Comment: Hm. I wonder anyway what's happening there. Usually, type casts are performed automatically. Few can be said without the precise code...

Comment: it looks like  the system needed a restart. now mathematica throw a warning the first few times i run cell and then it works without any problem